# Use structs to reduce the number of allocations

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

we have a complex class, which is widely used in our web application, with a lot of of all allocations and living instances. We try to improve the "time in GC" and therefore think about restructuring this class.

At the moment it looks like this:

```
class Main {
    public Child1 Property1;
    public Child1 Property2;

    public Child2 Property3;
    ...
}

class Child1 {
    public Geolocation Geolocation;
    public string Name;
    ...
}

class Geolocation {
    public double Lat;
    public double Lon;
}
```

There are a lot more properties in the root and child classes, most of them booleans and integers but also some strings an dictionaries. The objects of the child classes do not live without the parent and in most cases only the Main objects are passed around.

It is worth it to reduce some structs to reduce the number of allocations? e.g.

```
class Main {
    public Child1 Property1;
    public Child1 Property2;

    public Child2 Property3;
    ...
}

struct Child1 {
    public Geolocation Geolocation;
    public string Name;
    ...
}

struct Geolocation {
    public double Lat;
    public double Lon;
}
```

I know that this would not follow the most rules about structs, but it would reduce the number of allocations, increase cache locality and probably it makes garbage collection easier.

There are also some disadvantages, e.g. we have to care about passing this structs around and use ref parameters in some cases, but we think we can handle it. Are there also some other negative sideeffects I dont see?

Answer (score 1):

Sam Saffron writes in a very interesting blog post about a similar issue with garbage collection on the StackExchange sites:

> As a general rule: I would only consider porting to structs for cases where there is a large number (half a million or more) of medium lived objects. By medium lived, I mean, objects that are released shortly after they reach generation 2.

Source: **[In managed code we trust, our recent battles with the .NET Garbage Collector](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/28/in-managed-code-we-trust-our-recent-battles-with-the-net-garbage-collector)**